# How does debian/postinst know which package is being installed?

Tags: linux, package, debian, deb

I have debianized some source using "dh_make --native".  The control file specifies three packages:

```
blahd
libblahd1
libblahd1-dev
```

Now `blahd` has an `init.d` script, and whilst this gets put in `/etc/init.d` once the package is built and installed, it doesn't get enabled.  So I *think* I need to put something like:

```
insserv blahd
```

in debian/postinst. But how can I tell in debian/postinst whether it is `blahd` or `libblahd1` or `libblahd1-dev` that is being installed?

Comment: Doesn't it create one postinst per binary package?  So use `debian/libblahd1.postinst` and `debian/libblahd1-dev.postinst` to create two distinct scripts, or maybe generate these from a template.

Comment: And don't call `insserv` in your packages directly, use `invoke-rc.d` instead; see http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#s-sysvinit and http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html#initd

Comment: Thanks tripleee you answered the question I asked.  However, after reading the 2nd link provided by barti_ddu I realised I asked the wrong question.  I should have said: how do you add an init script and specify which package it should be added to.  I now know that the answer is to name the file debian/<pkg>.init.  If you do this dpkg-buildpackage automatically creates a postinst for you.  Cheers.

Comment: You'll probably want to write in an answer for yourself and 'Accept' it, so this question doesn't show up as unanswered.

Comment: Thanks Paul.  I'm new to this....  Unfortunately I can't now as it has been closed as off-topic.  I have no idea why it is considered off-topic however.  I'd appreciate being told so I can avoid doing it again.

Comment: I've re-opened this, @Alex - please edit the question to reflect your findings and post them as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was given by barti_ddu in a comment:

If your debian/control file specifies multiple packages, you can provide multiple init.d files   and specify which package each is for by naming them debian/`<package1>`.init, debian/`<package2>`.init and so on.

Thanks.